# How to edit /usr/include/dlfcn.h in mac

Tags: c++, linux, macos

I have to edit this file /usr/include/dlfcn.h ( a compilation for a package, and it's maintainer told me to add some lines in this file). But I can't edit it. It's read only. I use sudo chmod 777 to change it's permission, but I don't have the permission to change it. I tried , for example, sudo -s, or su, But I don't have permission.

Using "sudo", "sudo -s" , "su" are all the ways I know to get permission to change a file. But I failed in this case. So who knows the solution, can you help me?

I use osx 10.11 and xcode 7.3.1

Comment: Can you copy the `dlfcn.h` to a local directory and `-I` it so your modified file will be found before the system one?

Comment: I don't try it because I now not so familiar to osx. I am a little worry about it's a head file, and in C++ , we usually include a head file with a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

How did you continue after sudoing? You tried directly to open it with your editor and it didn't allow? (i.e. sudo gedit/vi/whatever dlfnc.h)

Comment: It is not because of the editor. Due to [System Integrity Protection](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) you can't modify anything in `/usr` on Mac even with root.

Comment: Oh... It's a different story then.